# Can this circuit with two resistors oscillate?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, oscillator, oscillation

From [these](https://slideplayer.com/slide/5957424/) lecture notes.

Can this circuit oscillate as the lecturer said?

[image]

I simulated this circuit in LTspice but it didn't work.

[image]

[image]

The step from 1V to 0V does have many frequency components if you do a Fourier analysis but I wouldn't consider it an oscillator.

Comment: Don't forget that an LC circuit is necessary to fix the "operating" frequency. The schematic shown is an ac "equivalent" ...

Comment: @Antonio51 but I want to check if it can oscillate without LC. Any frequency is okay, just want to confirm if it can oscillate or not.

Comment: Rglobal = 0 of the "function" is the condition for sustaining "oscillation". But the imaginary part of the "function" gives the "operating frequency". No imaginary part gives no "operating frequency" (f=0) ...

Comment: This could help https://www.theengineeringknowledge.com/introduction-to-tunnel-diode/

Comment: @Antonio51 that is a good point but the lecture said it does oscillate. The problem is that the frequency is not fixed. Now I'm trying to show if it can oscillate by simulating it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @emnha I think they are just saying to you that there is no gain above 1 for a noise signal at the shared node of the resistors until the negative resistance exceeds the positive resistance. But the moment that the negative resistance exceeds the positive resistance, the denominator in the resistor divider's equation moves through 0 (where an infinity results) and the gain magnitude becomes quite high for any noise that appears across the two series resistors as it appears at their shared junction. It's not complicated to see that fact.

Comment: @emnha ... yes, right, it must oscillate because ... there is always a "imaginary" part, but it must be modeled... Your picture does not mention any reactive component ... So, impossible to say. I am trying a simulation with a "mathematical" model (with a negative "local" resistance)... More to come ...

Comment: @Antonio51 that would be interesting if you can make the model work.

Comment: you should note that there is a negative resistor. If the positive resistor is bigger than the absolute value of the negative resistor there is a damped oscillation, if both are equal there is an oscillation with constant amplitude. If the absolute value of the negative resistor is bigger than the positive resistor there is an undamped oscillation. The amplitude will increase over time and the circuit will be destroyed finally.

Comment: A very popular negative-resistance oscillator with many versatile properties resembles a parallel combination of a classical (positive) ohmic resistor and an FDNR-block (active frequency-dependent negative resistor) based on a the well-known GIC principle).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't oscillate. It only has current opposite to the instantaneous voltage. There is no feedback effect, so no oscillation.

Comment: But LC oscillator does oscillate without feedback?

Comment: @emnha LC oscillators habe feedback: The forward current charges the capacitor creating a reverse voltage, that eventually turns the current around and so on.

Comment: Notice the _negative_ resistance. Then google for "tunnel diode oscillator."

Comment: @tobal LC dont have feedback. The energy in the capacitor is transformed to energy in the inductor and vice versa.

Comment: There are two basic oscillator concepts: (a) Negative resistance type and (b) selective feedback type. However, oscillator types (a) can always be seen and transferred to type.b oscillators (with feedback. Exception: Type-a tunnel diode based oscillators .

Answer (score 2):

This theoretical condition produces an infinite current (or a singularity) when R+ & R- = 0 and thus an infinite voltage across either resistor for any input voltage from a theoretical ideal voltage source of any voltage.

It is, but I wouldn't call this a feedback circuit just as I wouldn't call a perfect short circuit on an ideal voltage source a feedback circuit, yet there is a singularity condition, which feeds back infinite current to any voltage might look like a big bang or an oscillation depending on actual parasitic inductance and capacitance that occurs on all wire pairs.

There are many negative impedance devices such as the C-B feedback on transistors or the arc of a gas tube that drops voltage abuptly with a ionization arc of current. Tunnel Diodes and SCR's are different but with different shapes in their negative resistance.
Generators are defined to supply negative power, while loads dissipate positive power so that conservation of energy has a net-zero value in a system. That can be modeled as a negative source impedance and positive load. This can oscillate on long AC transmission if the impedance is inverted from quarter-wave reflection effects that invert impedance value and polarity of reactance.

This concept of +R & -R can become an oscillator in the more complex circuits, not as simple as shown such as a transmission line but with the same negative impedance features.

This method was used with POTS Telecom using a negative impedance line amplifier tuned with just slightly less negative impedance than the transmission line impedance to provide a stable gain in both directions so that they do NOT oscillate.  With voltage signals in one direction and current signals in the other and a Hybrid transformer at each end to the Subscriber Line Interface Card.

A perfect LC model will oscillate because the complex impedance adds up to zero only at one frequency. A real LC circuit always has some resistance in series or parallel, so it just needs a little stimulation to amplify into a steady sine oscillation.

I used this technique to inject 1 data transition in 1000 bits to make a stable oscillator lock its phase onto one data bit transition to sync a stable 4MHz clock then hold until the next frame. This can be called an Injection Locked Loop (ILL) or dynamic PLL tuned oscillator. A similar method was used on the original TV horizontal flyback sweep oscillator to synchronize and stabilize the picture with vacuum tube technology.

(this may need edits)

Answer (score 2):

Quote (emnha): *....I'm interested in the theory if two R, -R can oscillate with frequency unspecified*

No - this is imposible because this would violate the oscillation condition which requires that the loop gain is unity for ONE SINGLE FREQUENCY only!

A good example is the two-integrator loop which works as an oscillator (fixed oscillation frequency) only because the used opamps are REAL devices with a phase function that crosses the 90deg line at ONE SINGLE frequency only (both stages produce a 180deg phase shift at this frequency).

When we use instead an IDEAL opamp model without any real frequency dependence the oscillator would not work.

This is because the  phase of such an idealized integrator has a fixed 90deg-phase shift over a very broad frequency range (and a gain which is larger than unity). This also violates the oscillation condition (the circuit "does not know" at which frequency it should build up a rising oscillation amplitude).

This is one of the rare cases where an IDEAL unit will not work - but a real unit with otherwise parasitic properties does.

(See my comment to your question regarding the FDNR unit, which meets the oscillation condition R=-R at one single frequency only)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** EE&O, for those who are interested (and would check ... already pointed out by @Tony Stewart EE75 ...) in the behavior of the "negative" resistor, here is an example of what happens in a simple circuit... (DC Analysis). NB: forget L1, C1.
Nothing "weird"?

[image]

Now, here is a "quick" modeling of a "negative" function, ie ... a "negative" behavior.

DC characteristic of a "mathematical" function ...

[image]

And the TRAN simulation of this used "function".

And frequency is "imposed" by the external component (L, C, ...).
Note also that (for some conditions), the amplitude is greater than the DC input ...

[image]

EDIT: I have tried this circuit with a noise generator. No feedback.
Analysis of this behavior shows some interesting "things".

[image]

Comment: I thought you did model for R and -R only. I know how it can oscillate with LC and LC as a filter but I'm looking for a circuit with R and -R only.

Comment: Only trying to go to the "limit" where L (to infinity) and C (short-circuit) "disappear" ... Only remember that a true "negative" resistor doesn't "really" exist (ok, you can simulate it). If it was the case, I should be the "creator" of energy (which I am not) ... and I should be a trillionaire of trillionaire ... and more than that ...

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that but I'm interested in the theory if two R, -R can oscillate with frequency unspecified.

Comment: Made in the DC Analysis. Infinite current, + or - ... but "no" oscillation in this particular "resistive" case, because the system can't "swap" from positive to the negative region or vice-versa. Swapping is only permitted when system has "some" kind of "memory... And resistor don't have this. Except "memristor".

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to oscillate with no frequency determining components, i.e. it must pass through phase zero by backswing of an LC circuit (at resonance) or with an RC time constant where passing through the TC Notch (frequency).
A capacitor placed across the -ve resistance element (negistor) should provide a time constant with R1, and therefore should oscillate.